# How to perform a task when notification arrives and app is in terminated/killed state without any user interaction in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, terminate, application-state

I am trying to achieve one functionality in which I want to send one message to the server when I am receiving push notification but the app is in the terminated or killed state, and I also don't want user to tap on the notification or any other user interaction at all. Is this possible in iOS? However, there are some voice and video calling applications that use the priority push service called iOS VoIP Push Notifications using PushKit available in iOS, for instance, Whatsapp. But this only applies to this specific category of apps and by any means, if we implement Pushkit with no such relevance in our app, then the app will be rejected while submitting to store. Is there any solution available? Please suggest.

Comment: No, you can't do what you are asking.  More than just being rejected, in iOS13 if an app uses PushKit but doesn't indicate an incoming VoIP call after receiving the VoIP push, the app is terminated and blocked from receiving further pushes.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the quick response.